# Who invented "dooblidoo"?

Tags: etymology, slang, internet

The word [*dooblidoo*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dooblidoo) is used by several different youtube channels as a different word for the youtube description bar. I've seen it used by the [vlogbrothers](http://www.youtube.com/user/vlogbrothers) and by [PBS Idea Cahnnel](http://www.youtube.com/user/pbsideachannel).

Who was first to use and invent the term?

Comment: I suspect the term doobly doo is an onomatopoeia for "Down Below" which is the location of the YouTube description box relative to the video window. A common phrase on youtube is "I've put a link down below" down below, said often enough and fast enough sounds like doobly doo, which is I guess a little bit funny and easily emulated and it took off.

Comment: Frank Sinatra: https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tyfsrru6mjmq6kvkvlo35jsvpru?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics

Comment: (It's "scat". )

Comment: @HotLicks: that's "Doo-bee-doo-bee-doo"... that's different (though this new thing could, indeed, have derived from it, I don't know.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also spelt "doobly doo". There's a [related page here](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/doobly-doo) tracing usage of the term back to a guy called Craig Benzine (a Youtube user).

But to my ear, "doobly doo" sounds like a familiar idiom that's much older than that, used to name something you don't know the name of.

"*You know, the doobly doo ... the doobly doo for flipping eggs.*"

Comment: AKA Wheezy Waiter.

Comment: It does "sound familiar", because you've heard scat singing in many old 40s-50s era songs.

Comment: Is that US English? The equivalents in British English are "doo-dah", "doo-dad", "wotsit" and "thingummy". I've never heard "doobly doo"

Answer (score 3):

This first appears on WheezyWaiter and was popularized in part by vlogbrothers. Quoted from [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=doobly-doo):

> This term refers to the video description box on YouTube.
>
> This box, which contains information about the video, links, and tags,
> used to be universally referred to as the "sidebar," since it often
> appeared beside videos, but Craig Benzine (Wheezy Waiter) started
> referring to it as the "doobly-doo."
>
> Other YouTubers, such as John Green (part of the Vlogbrothers) and Dan
> Brown, started to also call the sidebar the "doobly-doo," using Wheezy
> Waiter's terminology (and crediting him in various comments and
> tweets). The term is now widely used on YouTube.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that the term is used in the song “Funky Monks” (1991) by the Red Hot Chili Peppers, though obviously not with the same meaning:

> Virtue slipped into my shoe
>   No I will not misconstrue
>   More rockin’ more rockin’ now doobley do
>   Dancin’ down your avenue

The nonsensical nature of the verse makes me think it might just be a placeholder word, perhaps with a longer history as @badroit suggests.

The English Project’s ["Kitchen Table Lingo"](https://books.google.com/books?id=arQT6K3VsTgC&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) (2008) [lists “doobly”](https://www.theguardian.com/uk/2008/jun/17/britishidentity) as an informal term for TV remote control, so its use as a technology-related placeholder is not unprecedented, at least in the UK.

Of course, Craig Benzine’s coinage might be completely independent.

Comment: That's just standard "scat", as used in jazz singing.

Comment: @HotLicks, that was my thinking too, and we know the Chilis were into some "old-timey" music (take their "They're Red Hot" cover). Chilis being Chilis, I half expect it to be a sex and/or drugs reference. :)